# List of Folders that do not contain a certain folder at a given depth

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to find the answer to the following question. I have been trying to list the directory trees that do not contain the folder "sample" at a given depth. The depth level will always be the same and I have been able to list all folders that contain the given folder by the following command however I can't seem to figure out how to list the directory trees that don't contain the folder.

**Here is the code I am using so far:**

```
@echo off
pushd e:\tv\
for /f %%a in ('dir /s/b/ad') do (
if /i "%%~na" EQU "sample" echo %%a >>c:\temp.txt
)
```

Again this code will produce all directory trees that contain the given folder, and will leave out the the ones that don't. If I switch the "EQU" to "NEQ" it will produce a list, but not at the proper depth level.

**Example:** - this will be my output from the script with "EQU"

```
 e:\TV\#\foo\foo\foo\Sample
```

When I switch the code to "NEQ" it will give me all folders including the ones with that sample folder in it.

I just want to produce a list of directories that do not contain the Sample folder on the 6th folder deep.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
PUSHD "U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('dir /b /s /ad') DO (
 REM tokenise - %%s gets level 3, %%t level 4 (level 0 is d:)
 FOR /f "tokens=4,5delims=\" %%s IN ("%%d") DO (
  IF "%%t"=="" (
   rem %%d is parent of 'sample'
   IF EXIST "%%d\sample" ECHO sample found IN %%d
  )
 )
)
popd    
GOTO :EOF
```

Note that I tested on a different level and using my test directory `u:\sourcedir`

with the directoryname list, tokenise using `\`. If the nth token exists and the (n+1)th does not, then this must be a parent directory. Note that if the nth token does not exist, the commands within the inner `for` will not be executed.

Hence, the question becomes "does the directory found contain `sample`?"

Well - `if exist` will detect that condition (OK - if a subdirectory *or file* named `sample` exists) and `if not exist` will detect its absence.

Comment: Thanks! - after some small tweaks it is working how I want now however I did have to change the numbers listed in the script to %%s = level 5, %%t = level 6, tokens = 6, 7delims.   Maybe I was wrong on levels, not sure, either way it is working great - thanks so much.